# Technique for finding cardinalites in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, functions

In combinatorics I see the following technique used a lot:
Let A and B be sets.
We try to find a function $f:A→B$ such that all the fibers of the elements of $B$ under $f$ have the same cardinality $\kappa$.
If we manage to do that, we conclude that $|A|=\kappa|B|$.

Example:
Find the number of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ whose cardinality is $2$.
Let A be the set of ordered pairs that have two distinct elements from $\{1,2,3,4\}$.
Let B be the set of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ whose cardinality is $2$.
Let $f:A→B$, $f(〈x,y〉)=\{x,y\}$.
The fiber of each $\{x,y\}∈B$ under $f$ has exactly $2$ elements: $〈x,y〉$ and $〈y,x〉$.
From that, we conclude that $|A|=2|B|$, and we know that
$|A|=4⋅3=12$, so we get $|B|=6$.

My questions:
Is there a name for this technique? Is there a name for this type of function?

Comment: Footnote: $f$ must be surjective.

Comment: No, because if $κ=0$, then A is empty, and therefore $|A|=κ|B|$, and if $κ>0$, then all the fibers are non-empty, and therefore $f$ is surjective

Comment: Depends on how you define fibers. If you define them as the members of the partition induced by function $f$ on its domain (as I am used to) then non-empty fibers do not exist. A partition has no empty elements.

Comment: The definition that I use is: The fiber of the element $y$ in the set $Y$ under a map $f : X → Y$ is the inverse image of the singleton $\{y\}$ under $f$.

Comment: Yours agrees with [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)#:~:text=Fiber%20in%20naive%20set%20theory,-Let%20f%20%3A%20X&text=That%20is%2C%20the%20fiber%20of,that%20are%20mapped%20to%20y.&text=If%20f%20is%20a%20continuous,hypersurface%20of%20dimension%20d%20%E2%88%92%201.). So in accordance with that my footnote is indeed redundant. Fortunately it is harmless too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is called overcounting. I sometimes hear $f$ described as a $\kappa$-to-one function, in analogy with a bijection being one-to-one.